# Deleting one of two indexes on same column on production

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I have postgreSQL, I have two indexes A and B on same column, I want to delete index B on production since it takes space. Is it safe to delete index on running database?

Table_column1 and column1 are two indexes on same column
[image]

Comment: Unless the database is partitioned, you can always do a drop index query with ```CONCURRENTLY``` option so that it doesn't block other queries

Comment: Just because they are on the same column doesn't mean they are identical.  They could be different methods or operators, different collations, etc.  You should look at the index definitions (for example with `pg_dump -s`, or other ways) to make sure they are really equivalent.  It is also best to know how it got there in the first place, or it might just reappear.

Comment: Most likely, your indexes are both used. I assume that `dx_scan` is really `idx_scan`. So it is not clear that either one can be dropped without affecting performance. To find unused indexes, see, for example: [Unused Indexes -PostgreSQL Database - Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/283136/unused-indexes-postgresql-database)

Comment: @TimurShtatland what happens if i delete less used index? I have storage problems , i wanna save space

Comment: @ElvinJafarov I assume that some queries will become slower. Which ones is hard to tell from your limited description. I recommend posting this (with your comment in the body of the question) as a new question. This way you will attract more attention. Otherwise, only a few people at most will see your comment above. Also, give more info about this table (definition of the table) and and indexes (definition of the indexes). It might be possible to use indexes on multiple columns and covering indexes, but more info is needed to answer this Q. Good luck!